# What other use do followers have?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have come across many people who I can hire to become my followers.

Are all the followers people who join you and fight along side you, or is there something more they can do?

There are archers, rogue's, thieves, warriors, mages and even a dog. But besides being a person to help fight, do they posses any other benefits?

Besides of course being able to carry a few more items for you, what is their purpose?

I've gone my whole game without a companion, and it was relatively easy. But do companions open different quests? Or other events in the game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things other than combat that a companions are good for

1. You must sacrifice a companion to start [Boethia's Calling](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Boethiah%27s_Calling).
2. Companions who are also trainers provide "free" training.  Simply take the gold you paid from their inventory.
3. Companions do not need lockpicks to open containers.

Answer (score 1):

Followers are sick because they well,follow you and do other stuff...Help you in battle,open locks,become a pack-mule and attack the bad guys....Just make sure you pick a person that compliments your play style. You really dont need two warriors. My character is a warrior but my follower is a mage. So as I'm caving skulls in my follower fries them with fire attacks. But as in anything else with Skyrim whatever you want to do to fit your style do it. It just happens to get a bit gnarly when two warriors are flailing around battle hammers and such.

Answer (score -2):

Followers can be used as a talking bag and as a meat shield.